# How to I copy data from a Swift 4 Data object to an OutputStream object?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to copy data from a Swift 4 Data object to an OutputStream.  The code that presumably worked on earlier versions is

```
let len = data.withUnsafeBytes {
    outputStream.write($0, maxLength: bytesRemaining)
```

XCode 9, however, complains

> Cannot convert value of type 'UnsafeRawBufferPointer' to argument type
>   'UnsafePointer

I also can't figure out how to advance the point in case that OutputStream accepts only part of the data.

Answer (score 1):

Your `data` is likely `[UInt8]`. The most convenient way to address this is to replace it with a `Data` value instead. The interface is quite similar, so it shouldn't have to change very much code other than the declaration. Alternately, you could copy the bytes into a `Data` like this:

```
let len = Data(data).withUnsafeBytes {
    outputStream.write($0, maxLength: bytesRemaining)
}
```

You can work directly on the `[UInt8]` by using an `UnsafeBufferPointer`:

```
let len = data.withUnsafeBufferPointer {
    if let address = $0.baseAddress {
        outputStream.write(address, maxLength: bytesRemaining)
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, “data” is, in fact, an instance of Data, so this takes us back to the original problem.  And $0.baseAddress doesn’t work either.

Comment: I can't reproduce your situation w/ Data and Xcode 9.4.1. Your code works fine if `data` is `Data`. I only see the error you're describing if `data` is `[UInt8]`.

Comment: Ah, yes!  Typo in superclass.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let data: NSData = dataToWrite
self.outputStream.write(UnsafePointer<UInt8>(data.bytes), maxLength: data.length)
```